# Does someone use a database to store observations?

Tags: tensorflow

i use tensorflow with real hardware, and every action and receiviing a new state takes some time (e.g. 3 seconds for a action) so i must store the already done actions and states for later re-use.

If i use python pickle and then after e.g. 15 hours of getting observations (around 23000) and then storing them takes too long (13GB around 15minutes) and then restoring them when running the tensorflow program again, takes the same time again.

So it would be nice, if the observations could be easily stored and restored from a  database?  Has someone done this?